# Custom UICollectionViewCell contentView animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I change the height of a `UICollectionViewCell` if a user touches it. To achieve that I use `performBatchUpdates:` to change the underlying data and use the standard cell animation. This works perfectly and the change gets animated with a standard grow and shrink animation.

Additionally I use `reloadSection` to update all subviews of the cells in that section. Here is my code:

```
[collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    dataHelper.isCellExpanded = !dataHelper.isCellExpanded;
 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section]];
}];
```

I need to achieve a flexible reordering of the subviews for the expanded cell state. So **I don't use Auto Layout**. I only change the subviews frame and would like to animate the frame change along with the `UICollectionViewCell` animation.

The Problem is that the subviews inside the `contentView` of the cells get updated without animation and **after** the height change animation of the cell is finished. But I would like to animate the cell subviews **along with** the animation of the height change. How would one implement that?

**UPDATE**

A custom animation method in my `UICollectionViewCell` looks like this:

```
- (void)animate {
 [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                       delay:0.0
                     options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                  animations:^
 {
     CGRect labelFrame = self.testLabel.frame;
     labelFrame.origin.y += 70;
     self.testLabel.frame = labelFrame;
 }
 completion:nil];
}
```

I create the `testLabel` in the `initWithFrame:` of my `UICollectionViewCell` subclass like so:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) {
      CGRect cellFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);

      // content
      _testLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, frame.size.height - 20, frame.size.width - 20, 20)];
      _testLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
      _testLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
      _testLabel.text = @"test";
      [self.contentView addSubview:_testLabel];
      ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement an animation method inside the collection view cell and you need to that call from the performBatchUpdates method.

```
[collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    dataHelper.isCellExpanded = !dataHelper.isCellExpanded;
    // Access the cells you want to animate
    yourCustomCell *cell = (yourCustomCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell animate];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section]];
}];
```

Inside the cell animate method you can implement all the animations you might want.

Comment: This does nothing. I added an `animate` method to my cell. Inside this method I call a standard `animateWithDuration`. The code gets called, but there is no animation.

Comment: How does your animation implementation look like?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by just adding springs and struts to the `contentView` and to the `testLabel` in my `UICollectionViewCell` subclass in the form of `autoresizingMask`

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) {
      CGRect cellFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);

      self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

      // content
      _testLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, frame.size.height - 20, frame.size.width - 20, 20)];
      _testLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
      _testLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
      _testLabel.text = @"You rock";
      _testLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
      [self.contentView addSubview:_testLabel];
```

Side note:
I was playing around with AutoLayout to fix this issue but was never able to get it to work.